# Convert One Java Class to Differrent Json Formats

Tags: java, spring-rest

I have a use case where I  have one dto class that has all the data retrieved from a db call. I need  to create different  json formats  using information from that class.
What is the best way to do this?.Also is there a way to do this with out making a code change everytime a new json format is needed ,something like storing the different json schemas in a persistence layer and then
do the mapping dynamically ?

Comment: Do you want to marshall the dto or just apply the value to different schemas ?

Comment: Apply the value to different schemas would be the primary use case .A secondary use case would be to do  minimal transformations to some of the values derived from DTO  before applying to json

Comment: The simplest and the fastest way to do is first convert all your schema's to some pojo's so that you can easily set the data from the origin dto that you are saying and then generate json using any library of your choice. So if you are able to generate and store the pojo's then it should be pretty much straight forward.

Comment: alternatively, let's say that you have a very massive json from which you need only certain info on different schemas then you can choose something like graphql which will be a suitable usecase

Comment: Can you provide some examples of formats ?

Answer (score 0):

I provide below my simple thoughts. Suppose you have a dto class say EmpDto which has data in relation to your database table model. If you want to create a json in way different way, then you create a separate object model like EmpJsonBean and annotate the Json annotations from Jackson framework. You have to populate the EmpJsonBean by taking required data from the EmpDto class. This way you can do it.

If you think of a design pattern so that you can have minimal impact, I would suggest for Adapter design pattern so that you can have a different json structure based upon the business need.